# Should you set 'Vary: Origin' when allowing any CORS origin (*)?

Tags: http, caching, http-headers, cors, cdn

For a server supporting CORS and wanting to handle caching as efficiently as possible, is it necessary to set `Vary: Origin` if you know that CORS responses will never vary according to the request origin via `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`?

I've read several guides on the subject, and most recommend using `Vary: Origin`, but in the common CORS case of explicitly allowing any origin, this seems inefficient and unnecessary.

Thanks!

Comment: I recommend reading the entire spec section at  https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-protocol-and-http-caches *“If CORS protocol requirements are more complicated than setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `*` or a static origin, `Vary` is to be used… However, if `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is set to `*` or a static origin for a particular resource, then configure the server to always send `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in responses for the resource — for non-CORS requests as well as CORS requests — and do not use `Vary`.”*

Answer (score 4):

If your responses *don't* change depending on the `Origin` header, then you need to leave it out of `Vary`.

Vary is specifically for headers that alter the response.

For example, if your client can use an `Accept` request header, and depending on the value the server might return different data, then you need `Vary: Accept`.

Comment: Yeah, I totally understand what Vary means -- this question is about the specific CORS use case which every single CDN's docs I've found recommends to set anyway regardless of whether or not your server logic varies with respect to `Origin`.

Comment: Though I really do appreciate your answer 

Comment: @fisch2 my answer still 100% applies, regardless of the case you describe. It's not special case.